# Close to removing login with touch id feature! How to handle customer frustration?

Tags: ios, login, touch-screen

Due to regulatory measures,  we have to cancel touch id login feature on our mobile banking app.  We know thousands of customers are already using it.  What do you suggest for handling frustration online and offline :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ouch! No matter why this happened you have to deal with your frustrated users. It doesn’t matter if you didn’t read the terms properly or if Apple change something along the way – you have a serious usability issue.

What you can do is to explain that this happened. It may ease the pressure some of your users feel, and the one topic to grasp that users understand is (you guessed it) security! Users tend to accept almost any form of sometimes over protective behavior as long as we tell them it’s a security issue. Users like simplicity but they don’t want to compromise or jeopardize security.

To give an example, it would be the simplest of things to implement a banking app without any security and just by the phone ID give users access to their bank. It would feel secure since its only available through this phone with this phone-ID. But if you lost the phone, your banking activities could be used by somebody else. And users don’t like the next person on the bus stop to view your bank. Moreover, that person could empty your well-earned salary with just a few clicks.

That’s why banking in particular needs two-factor authentication to verify your credentials. Its technical, but basically you need two different channels to authenticate who you are. It’s like your passport where the authentication issuer (the state or country) have authorized who you are with a photo, your length and height and now a day also with fingerprint scan, eye recognition and other biometric authentication methods to prove to the one trying to validate your identity that you are the one that you say you are.

Using a commercialized type-of fingerprint scanner isn’t really good enough. You need to have a second channel besides your finger to prove who you are. It may be an SMS, Google authenticator, Bank-ID or an e-mail which is not accessible by any other than you.

So go back to your customers and say that you want to protect their balance so that nobody else uses it, and that fraud is avoided. I’m confident your user will accept SECURITY as the real issue here and that you take care of them before something bad happens. A preventive action is at its best when it’s not driven by a corrective action.

Comment: Hey Benny,  thanks for your detailed answer. I should say that,  touch id login is not the only method for signing in,  but although it is optional,  many users prefer it and use it for the last 10 months,  they are keen on using it.  We will tell them that it is for maintaining higher security,  but i think most of them would think that since it is not the only option,  it should have continued.  Anyway,  thank you again.